# Materials don't work when switching from Cycles Render to Blender Game

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, game-engine

[image]

I created an object and I have created a material under the Cycles Render while using material viewport shading. If I switch to Blender Game Engine, this is what I see

[image]

My question is how do I solve this and return the object back to the way it was in Blender Game Engine?

Answer (score 2):

The Cyles engine is different than the Blender Game Engine and you can only have textures from Cycles into BGE(not exactly the same but similar quality) by baking them. (Search baking textures)

You can just go back to see your material by changing the top from Game Engine to Cycles Engine.